# Xamarin: Applying typeface for all container's children

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm using this code for applying typeface to all views in my layout:

```
var mainLayout = FindViewById<RelativeLayout>(Resource.Id.mainLayout);
for (int i = 0; i < mainLayout.ChildCount - 1; i++)
            {
                if (mainLayout.GetChildAt(i) is TextView)
                {
                    ((TextView)mainLayout.GetChildAt(i)).SetTypeface(tf, TypefaceStyle.Bold);
                }
                else if (mainLayout.GetChildAt(i) is EditText)
                {
                    ((EditText)mainLayout.GetChildAt(i)).SetTypeface(tf, TypefaceStyle.Bold);
                }
                else if (mainLayout.GetChildAt(i) is Button)
                {
                    ((Button)mainLayout.GetChildAt(i)).SetTypeface(tf, TypefaceStyle.Bold);
                }

            }
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_pattern"
                android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_dexcription_logo"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        style="@style/AuthTitle" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subtitle"
        style="@style/AuthTitle.AuthSubtitle" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/editTextLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/subtitle"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/login_vertical_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/login_box_radius"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/login_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/login_horizental_padding"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/login_horizental_padding"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/login_vertical_margin">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/usernameField"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/username_hint"
            android:textColorHighlight="@color/light_gray"
            android:textSize="17sp">
            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/passwordField"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/password_hint"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textColorHighlight="@color/light_gray"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textSize="17sp" />
        <Button
            android:text="Login"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnLogin" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

But, it applies just to `TextView`s.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop the children that are ViewGroups themselves. Currently your code just ignores them.

Furthermore no need to check if it's Button or EditText, because both of them extend TextView, therefore it's enough to check if it's an instance of TextView.

Here's an example in plain java/android:

Recursive method:

```
public void loopViewGroup(ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    for (int i=0; i<viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
        if (child instanceof TextView) {
            // Extends TextView (EditText, Button etc.)
            ((TextView) child).setTypeface(tf, TypefaceStyle.Bold);
        } else if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
            // Is a ViewGroup (layout)
            loopViewGroup((ViewGroup) child);
        }
    }
}
```

Start the method like this:

```
loopViewGroup(findViewById(R.id.mainLayout));
```